# Как в unity сделать, чтобы камера всегда смотрела на один объект?

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы камера была привязана к одному объекту и смотрела все время на другой. Мне нужно чтобы скрипт был все время на одном расстояние от одного объекта и другой был ровно по середине экрана. написал такой скрипт.

```
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject Player;
public GameObject Enemy;

private Vector3 offset;

private void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - Enemy.transform.position;
}

private void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Enemy.transform.position - transform.position);

    transform.position = Player.transform.position + offset;
}
}
```

По отдельности вроде все работает, но когда вместе не работает. Как еще можно реализовать мою задачу

Comment: А Вы не пробовали сначала изменять расположение камеры, а только затем менять угол поворота?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский, А если я правильно понимаю, то поворот (Rotation) никак не связан с позицией (position)? Можно как-то сделать, чтобы всегда это было линией

Comment: в расчете поворота камеры у Вас используется ее положение. Камеру Вы повернули корректно для предыдущего положения. Но затем Вы передвигаете камеру.
Попробуйте наоборот.

Comment: @ АлександрДаниловский, Пробовал, ничего нормального не получалось

Answer (score 2):

```
public Transform target;

void Update()
{
    // Rotate the camera every frame so it keeps looking at the target
    transform.LookAt(target);
}
```

Взято из:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

кейворды по которым нашел "unity camera look at"

Answer (score 0):

Для управления камерой подойдет бесплатный плагин [Cinemachine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAeEzgqjdLI). Сложновато разбираться, но если справитесь то камера у вас и не такие чудеса будет делать. Для простеньких действий это как из пушки по воробьям, а вот для чего-то серьезного очень советую.